# MLE of Weibull hazard and lognormal frailty in R?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, survival

Consider a Gaussian random variable $\log(U)$, with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. How can the parameter estimates of the corresponding log-normal frailty model (i.e the frailty random variable is U which follows a log-normal distribution) be obtained? The hazard distribution can assumed to be Weibull.

The `parfm` package (in R) assumes $\log(U)$ has a mean of zero.

Answer (score 1):

$\mu$ is fixed (to zero) to ensure identifiability of the parameters in the frailty model, similar to the zero-mean constraint for the random effects in the linear mixed model.

In other terms, $\mu$ plays the same role as the scale parameter of the Weibull baseline hazard.

Comment: I suppose the identifiability condition requires E(U) = 1 which can only be satisfied if log(U)~N( -log(1+s)/2, log(1+s) ). Here, s denotes the variance of U.

Comment: E(U) = 1 is not mandatory. What is important is that it is fixed (rather than a parameter). In general, it is the more convenient for the sake of interpretability, though. When U follows a log-normal distribution, the typical choice is to take E(log(U)) = 0 by similarity with the linear model.